# I can't find any hard drive after Windows update

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I have my laptop set up as a dual-system Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.04.
Everything worked fine until this morning, when Windows 10 tried to update. Currently, I cannot boot any of the two OS anymore -- I can be more specific if needed.

I am mentally prepared to lose my data, so I thought that re-installing everything would be the quickest solution.

I run boot-info from Ubuntu LiveCD, this is the result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GtQQDxTFhr/
I don't know how to read all of the information. But I cannot locate my HD in any of the output. When I try to proceed with Ubuntu installation, it does not give me the option to install on the HD.

Any suggestion on how to proceed? Again, I don't care about recovering data I just want a working computer with Ubuntu.

Comment: Does BIOS detect the hdd?  When using the live Ubuntu (ie. 'try-ubuntu') I'd load `smartmontools` then look at `smartctl` output.  If smartctl can't find the drive I'd be checking connectors & drive physically, but it may provide some health clues (its reads data from circuits on drive, not platters/heads or drive mechanics).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue and got back my data as well. It turns out that Windows automatically changed the SATA controller in the UEFI settings to Intel Rapid Storage Technology instead of AHCI. Setting back the SATA controller to AHCI solved the issue and everything turned back to normality.

I am just wondering how comes that an update of the OS could change the UEFI settings. But perhaps this is common and I have never noticed.

Comment: I have changed  multiple UEFI settings. And if I do an update to UEFI, most settings revert to defaults. (With BIOS all settings changed to defaults). So I keep a list of setting changes and reset them. Did you also do an update to UEFI. I have seen others where Windows resets to first in boot order (as does grub on updates), but may also turn fast start up back on preventing grub from booting Windows.

Comment: No I did not update the UEFI, but you are right -- Windows resetted to first in boot order. But that was easy to diagnose. Yet, I did not expect a change on the SATA controller...but who am I to know?